# How to write unit/integration tests in python with rabbitmq?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, rabbitmq, automated-tests

I have a python project written using rabbitmq, and I'm wondering how I should write unit tests for it/what are best practices.

Since the code requires a rabbitmq server to be running in the background these are the three options I've come up with:

1. write some checker that checks at the start of a test suite whether rabbit is running and fails if it doesn't - not ideal because it requires the manual starting of rabbitmq
2. automatically start a process with rabbitmq on each test setUp and kill it on tearDown - for some reason this creates connection errors
3. mock out rabbitmq - does anyone have any suggestions or tips on this one?

Thanks!

Jon

Answer (score 1):

Defenitly I prefer to left rabbitmq out of unit test.

I'm re writing a fake upper class to avoid Rabbit mq dependencies and it gives me few interfaces to call publisher method or call one receiver checker method.

```
class FakePublisher(Publisher)
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def call_consumer(self, msg):
        self.consumer(msg)

class test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        publisher = FakePublisher()
        ret = publisher.call_consumer(msg("foo"))
        self.assertEqual(ret, True)
```